# Sailsjs disable javascript files auto linking in layout.ejs

Tags: sails.js

I have a SailsJS project. In the layout.ejs, it automatically add all the files under assets/js folder to the layout.ejs, even those irrelevant ones. I guess good for single page web-application. But I am looking to have a few other pages so hope to select the js files I would like to add on each page.

Question: how to disable the auto-linking in layout.ejs to allow me to selectively include javascript files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open tasks/pipeline.js

In pipeline.js you can set what files and in which order your css, javascript, and template files should be compiled and linked

For disabling auto-linking javascript files, just empty the jsFilesToInject Array.